# How to create an array with 'a' repeated 'b' times

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a function that takes in two vairables `a` and `b`, this function will create an array with variable `a` reapeated `b` times.

This is how far I have gone but It's not outputting th correct number of items in the array:

```js
var createArr = function(a, b) {
    // returns an array with variable a repeated b times.
    if (typeof b == 'number') {
      var arr = [];

      for (var i = 0; i <= b; i++) {
        arr.push(a);
      };
    }
      return arr;
    };
    
 createArr("ready",3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy:

```js
function createArr(a, b) {
    return Array(b).fill(a);
}
```

Comment: @RoboRobok You might want to check out [why we mark questions as duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) in the first place. We're not here to be a helpdesk and grab some internet points. We're here to make a library of high quality Q&A's that can be used by people beyond the person asking. Marking questions as duplicates helps to reach that goal by keeping the high-quality and up-to-date answers in one place. (Also, two wrongs don't make a right. Answering duplicates because others also do it doesn't justify it.)

Answer (score 1):

If you use <= and the value “3” for “b”, the loop will run once for 0, 1, 2, and 3. Oops, that’s 4 times.

Instead you want to use < so the loop will run once for 0, 1, then 2, and *not* for 3.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fencepost_error

Answer (score 0):

for loop, break will be `<` not  `<=` because when `<=` for loop start with 0 and break when it 3 so loop 4 times when need to loop 3 times so need an use `<`

```js
var createArr = function(a, b) {
    // returns an array with variable a repeated b times.
    if (typeof b == 'number') {
      var arr = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        arr.push(a);
      };
    }
      return arr;
    };
    
 console.log(createArr("ready",3));
```